# How to clear combo box contents in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

If for textbox it is `textbox1.clear`, etc.
What is the equivalent for combobox to clear the value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using `combobox.Items.Clear()`

Comment: I figured it out, and its this one:
ComboBox1.ResetText

Comment: @dean-harding this gives `items collection cannot be modified when the datasource property is set` exception

Comment: @Osama Rizwan   Add this line ComboBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()

Answer (score 4):

If your `combobox` is set with the `DropDownList`, then
use `Combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1`

Answer (score 0):

To clear the items that are in the drop down menu `combobox.SelectedIndex = -1` will work.
To clear what the user types in the combobox `combobox.Text = String.Empty` will work because the combobox also has a text property. Use both of these to ensure it will clear the fields.

Answer (score 0):

first null the the datasource
`combobox.DataSource = Nothing`
then clear the combobox `combobox.Items.Clear()`

Answer (score 0):

When I need to clear a combo box, I use

```
combobox1.text=""
```