# How do I clear a combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have some combo-boxes that are set up as drop down lists, and the user can pick a number in them. I also have a Clear button that should clear the text from the combo boxes but I can't seem to get it. I've tried:

```
 //doesn't work
 cboxHour.Text = "";
```

and

```
//doesn't work
cboxHour.ResetText();
```

This seems like it should be so straight forward but I'm just not getting it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear combo box contents in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458928/how-to-clear-combo-box-contents-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Did you try `cboxHour.Items.Clear()`?

Comment: That's the winner. I'll mark you as the chosen answer when I can.

Comment: If your comboBox is data bounded then set comboBoxName.DataSource = null before Clearing

Comment: This is likely insufficient. Calling ResetText() as answered by @beanmf below is likely also required.

Comment: In case of 'DataSource' property of a combobox used, we have to assign null as follows : modeComboBox.DataSource = null;
(modeComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);)

Answer (score 92):

If you just want to clear the current selection, but leave all of the items in the list, you can use:

```
cboxHour.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Comment: When I employ this, the selectedIndexChanged event fires.  In SelectedIndexChanged event, I return out of the eventif SelectedIndex is -1.

Answer (score 25):

When `ComboBox` is not data-bound, I've found I need both:  `Clear()` removes the items but still leaves the `SelectedItem`'s text, while `ResetText()` removes that text.  **VS2008**.

```
ComboBox.Items.Clear();
ComboBox.ResetText();
```

Comment: Agreed on above. I was having the same problem in VS2013, where the 4 calls Items.Clear(), SelectedIndex=-1, SelectedText=string.empty, and SelectedText=string.empty was insufficient. Items.Clear() followed by ResetText() did the trick.

Answer (score 16):

You can use

```
Cbo.Items.Clear();
```

or

```
Cbo.DataSource = null;
```

if you have a binding on it.

Answer (score 8):

Answer for your question is:

```
metroComboBox1.SelectedItem = null;
anycomboBox1.SelectedItem=null;
```

Comment: combox.items.clear() deletes the items from the list while setting the selected item to null clears the selected data. excellent. thanks.

Comment: if you are having trouble setting the index to -1, try setting the selecteditem to null or nothing.  This worked for me.

Comment: This is the real answer. It also solves an issue I had with .ResetText - then, I wasn't able any more to programmatically re-load a selection. But .SelectedItem = null does the trick. Excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
cboxHour.Items.Clear();
```

this works

Comment: Can you expand on your answer a little? It's great if you can provide a little bit of context to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you have applied datasource to combobox, then it will not be cleared as `cmb.Items.Clear()`.

For that you have to assign datasource `null` to combobox.

```
cmb.DataSource = null;
cmb.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 4):

If there is value binding part for your combobox. Use below code to clear its value:

```
cboxHour.SetSelectedIndex(-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
comboBox1.ResetText();
```

and it's done.

Docs: ComboBox.ResetText Method (Namespace: System.Windows.Forms)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.resettext?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Mine worked with:

```
ComboBox.removeAllItems();
```

If it doesn't read that well its, remove all items.

Answer (score 0):

Combo Box, DropDown all are having the same logic to clear/remove all items from them and it is like below.

```
//For checkbox list
cblTest.Items.Clear();

//For drop down list
ddlTest.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Resetbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    comboBox1.Items.Clear(); // it will clear a combobox

    comboBox1.Items.Add("Student"); //then add combobox elements again. 
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Staff");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF You can try this code

cbHours.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below option for clearing the selected text and all items from the ComboBox.

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I added `ComboBox.Focus()`

```
ComboBox.Items.Clear();
ComboBox.ResetText();
ComboBox.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

**> Its work for me:**

```
    ComboCapacity.DataSource = null;
    ComboCapacity.Items.Clear();
    ComboCapacity.ResetText();
```

Answer (score 0):

My Soluce to Clear DropDownList ComboBox C# VS2022

```
ComboBox _ComboBox = new ComboBox();
_ComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
_ComboBox.DataSource = DataTablexxx;
_ComboBox.DisplayMember = "xxxx";
_ComboBox.ValueMember = "Idn";
//Enable the form now
this.Visible = true;
this.ResumeLayout(false);
this.PerformLayout();
//Select the item by ident saved
_ComboBox.SelectedValue = Properties.Settings.Default.Idn;
```

On Event Button :

```
_ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
_ComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have just changed the text of the combobox, like this:

```
Combobox.Text = "Select...";
```

Comment: This changes what is in the text portion and not clear the combo box as requested. Your response assumes that "Select..." was the default in there. You also don't say after you did it whether it solved the problem