# ComboBox Values Keeps getting added to the list

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a form with two comboboxes .

combobox1 unitupc

combobox2 production line

First, the unitupc gets loaded and then for each unitupc chosen the combobox2 gets populated. The issue I am having is that for each unitupc chosen by the user the previous values is stored in the combobox2 and the list keeps getting added, how does one clear the combobox each time the unitupc is chosen and reload it in?

Here is a picture of the form with the issue i am talking about:

[image]

**EDIT CODE ADDED**

```
  private void DimensionSelection_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CorsicanaNetWeightDataSet10.Net_Weight_Master_Data_Report' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'corsicanaNetWeightDataSet9.ProductionLine' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

            prodline = new productweightdataset();
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'corsicanaNetWeightDataSet3.ProductionLine' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //this.productionLineTableAdapter.Fill(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet3.ProductionLine,comboBox3.Text.ToString());
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'corsicanaNetWeightDataSet2.ItemDescription' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //this.itemDescriptionTableAdapter.Fill(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet2.ItemDescription);

            loadprod(); 

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            reportViewer1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
            //{
            //    button1.Enabled = true;
            //}

            Loadproduction();
            comboBox2.Refresh();
        }

        private void loadprod()
        {
            try
            {
                using (MSSQL.SqlConnection connection = new MSSQL.SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (MSSQL.SqlCommand command = new MSSQL.SqlCommand("SELECT [Unit UPC Base Item] as Unitupc, [Item Description] AS ItemDescription FROM ItemDesc", connection))
                    {
                        {
                            MSSQL.SqlDataAdapter myadapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
                            myadapter.SelectCommand = command;
                            myadapter.Fill(prodline, "DataTable1");

                        }

                    }

                    //fill drop down
                    comboBox1.DataSource = prodline.DataTable1;
                    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ItemDescription";
                    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemDescription";
                    comboBox3.DataSource = prodline.DataTable1;
                    comboBox3.ValueMember = "Unitupc";
                    comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Unitupc";
                    if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                    {

                        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        Loadproduction();
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { /*Handle error*/ }


        }



        //private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    this.productionLineTableAdapter1.Fill(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet9.ProductionLine, comboBox3.Text.ToString());
        //}

        private void Loadproduction()
        {
           if (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (MSSQL.SqlConnection connection = new MSSQL.SqlConnection(constr))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        using (MSSQL.SqlCommand command = new MSSQL.SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.[Production Lines].[Production Line Description] AS prodline FROM dbo.[Production Lines] LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Net Weight Master Data] ON dbo.[Production Lines].[Production Line] = dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Production Line] RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemDesc ON dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Unit UPC Base Item] = dbo.ItemDesc.[Unit UPC Base Item] WHERE (dbo.ItemDesc.[Unit UPC Base Item] = '0001') GROUP BY dbo.[Production Lines].[Production Line], dbo.[Production Lines].[Production Line Description], dbo.ItemDesc.[Unit UPC Base Item] ORDER BY dbo.ItemDesc.[Unit UPC Base Item]", connection))
                        {
                            MSSQL.SqlParameter myparam = new MSSQL.SqlParameter();
                            myparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                            myparam.ParameterName = "@unitupc";
                            myparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                            myparam.Size = 50;
                            myparam.Value = comboBox3.Text;
                            command.Parameters.Add(myparam);
                            MSSQL.SqlDataAdapter myadapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
                            myadapter.SelectCommand = command;
                            myadapter.Fill(prodline, "DataTable2");
                            comboBox2.DataSource = prodline.DataTable2;
                            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "prodline";


                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception) { /*Handle error*/ }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What language is this? Where's your code?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling sorry i thought i added the code, I have included the code in the above question. plz help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clear a combobox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321844/how-do-i-clear-a-combobox)

Comment: @j0h4nn3s That link you provided won't work when the ComboBox is using a DataSource.

Comment: @LarsTech There is also an answer which is considering a DataSource

Comment: @j0h4nn3s I still don't think that would help the OP.  That LoadProduction call looks like the culprit to me since it keeps filling the same DataTable that gets used as the DataSource for that ComboBox.  The Fill method of a DataAdapter doesn't clear the existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have to clear the DataSource of Combobox, before binding the new values. Use Clear to clear the DataTable as @LarsTech as suggested. See my edits

```
  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {         
        comboBox2.DataSource = null;
        Loadproduction();
        comboBox2.Refresh();
  }
```

Edit:

```
 private void Loadproduction()
 {
      if (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MSSQL.SqlConnection connection = new MSSQL.SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (MSSQL.SqlCommand command = new MSSQL.SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.[Production Lines].[Production Line Description] AS prodline FROM dbo.[Production Lines] LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Net Weight Master Data] ON dbo.[Production Lines].[Production Line] = dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Production Line] RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemDesc ON dbo.[Net Weight Master Data].[Unit UPC Base Item] = dbo.ItemDesc.[Unit UPC Base Item] WHERE (dbo.ItemDesc.[Unit UPC Base Item] = '0001') GROUP BY dbo.[Production Lines].[Production Line], dbo.[Production Lines].[Production Line Description], dbo.ItemDesc.[Unit UPC Base Item] ORDER BY dbo.ItemDesc.[Unit UPC Base Item]", connection))
                    {
                        MSSQL.SqlParameter myparam = new MSSQL.SqlParameter();
                        myparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        myparam.ParameterName = "@unitupc";
                        myparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                        myparam.Size = 50;
                        myparam.Value = comboBox3.Text;
                        command.Parameters.Add(myparam);
                        MSSQL.SqlDataAdapter myadapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
                        myadapter.SelectCommand = command;
                        prodline.DataTable2.Clear(); //or u can use prodline.DataTable2.Reset() --Reset removes all data, indexes, relations, and columns of the table
                        myadapter.Fill(prodline, "DataTable2");
                        comboBox2.DataSource = prodline.DataTable2;
                        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "prodline";


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { /*Handle error*/ }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @HackMaster Try to Use LarsTech Answer along with my answer. Clear the DataTable and also Clear the DataSource before bind new values

Comment: combining the solutions worked but i used the clear instead of reset because the reset made my combobox 2 empty, thanks for the assistance appreciate it!!!!.

Answer (score 2):

You keep filling the DataTable, so clear it first:

```
prodLine.DataTable2.Rows.Clear();
myadapter.Fill(prodline, "DataTable2");
```

Comment: i tried your solution i am getting the following error, cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

Comment: @HackMaster Did you type it exactly? Try `prodLine["DataTable2"].Rows.Clear();` instead.  Make sure that table exists before you call that line.

Comment: i tried this prodline.DataTable2.Rows.Clear(); its not working, i am still getting the cannot implicitly convert 'void' to object plz help!!

Comment: @HackMaster That isn't what I wrote.  You clear the table of the rows, fill the table (if you must), then set the DataSource.  Your DataSource line shouldn't change.

Comment: combining your solution and prasy's solution worked appreciate the help. i was getting the error because in the solution you had prodLine.DataTable2.Rows.Clear(); but it had to be prodline :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this already: `ComboBox2.Items.Clear()`?

EDIT: I'll go with prasy's answer. Look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321844/how-do-i-clear-a-combobox) for more information.

Comment: it is still doing the same thing