# How to remove the text selection highlight from a ComboBox permanently?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am interested in removing the text selection of ComboBoxes with `DropDownStyle = DropDown`.
When I add/remove or close the DropPown, then the Item is selected.
I am not able to clear the selected text. Do you have some idea how to do this?

This code does not work:

```
comboBox.SelectionLenght = 0;
comboBox.SelectionStart = comboBox.Text.Legnth;
comboBox.Select(0,0);
```

I can see that the text is highlighted after this line:

```
selectedComboBox.Items.Add(redCompetitorName);
```

Comment: Some alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321844/how-do-i-clear-a-combobox

Comment: @FelipeOriani I don't want to clear the items, I added them because I need them. In addition, I don't want to clear the text, only the highlight

Answer (score 4):

You can defer the execution of the `Select()` method, calling [BeginInvoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler (or [SelectionChangedCommitted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted), if you want this to happen only when a User selects an Item *manually*).

By deferring the execution (this *action* is enqueued in the message loop),   the `Select()` action is performed only after the `ComboBox.Text` has been set and highlighted. So your command is not overridden by the default behavior.

```
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set the caret to the start of the ComboBox text
    BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> comboBox.Select(0, 0)));

    // OR - set the caret to the end of the text instead
    BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> comboBox.Select(int.MaxValue, 0)));
}
```

This *concept* applies in other contexts of course.
You can use this method in other situations, when you need to perform an action, in the UI, that is executed only after the current (or the current sequence of the already *scheduled* actions) has completed.

If you want a more *involved* solution that prevents all kind of selection highlights in a ComboBox, you can use a Custom Control derived from ComboBox, [get the Handle of its Edit Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo), use a [NativeWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow) to intercept its messages. Override WndProc to handle [EM_SETSEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setsel) and call [PostMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagew) to remove the selection (only when the starting position is > 0, otherwise you risk to get stuck in a weird auto-loop which has an *effect* that's usually referred to as StackOverflow :).

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("code")]
public class ComboBoxNoFocus : ComboBox
{
    IntPtr editHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    private EditNativeWindow editControl = null;

    public ComboBoxNoFocus() { }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        editHandle = GetComboBoxEditInternal(this.Handle);
        editControl = new EditNativeWindow(editHandle);
    }


    public class EditNativeWindow : NativeWindow
    {
        private const int EM_SETSEL = 0x0B1;
        public EditNativeWindow() : this(IntPtr.Zero) { }
        public EditNativeWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero) {
                this.AssignHandle(handle);
            }
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg) {
                case EM_SETSEL:
                    int pos = m.LParam.ToInt32();
                    if (pos > 0) {
                        PostMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETSEL, 0, 0);
                    }
                    return;
                default:
                    // Other operations
                    break;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct COMBOBOXINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public Rectangle rcItem;
        public Rectangle rcButton;
        public int buttonState;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndEdit;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
        public void Init() => this.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<COMBOBOXINFO>();
    }

    internal static IntPtr GetComboBoxEditInternal(IntPtr cboHandle)
    {
        var cbInfo = new COMBOBOXINFO();
        cbInfo.Init();
        GetComboBoxInfo(cboHandle, ref cbInfo);
        return cbInfo.hwndEdit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the focus to another control in your form after a new item is selected, using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the Combobox.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Focus();
}
```